# Trying to connect either a database to an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, phpmyadmin

I'm currently building a website in ASP.NET C# and am trying to connect a user database to it. I have the database as a phpmyadmin setup on another server (raspberry pi) or as a windows Access file. I would honestly prefer to connect directly to the phpmyadmin but would be fine with connecting the access file. I am confused as where to begin on either solution. Please could someone provide some help.

This is my first time using this website so I'm sorry if I seem to be rambling on about things people don't tend to need to know. I am also new to C# in general so sorry if anything I'm asking about is something that people know doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a database. You want to connect to it.

> I have the database as a phpmyadmin setup on another server

STOP!!! What are you talking about? If you have MySQL setup and running on some machine, then state as such. phpmyadmin is NOT a database, and has ZERO ZERO to do with this question.

> or as a windows Access file.

A "file" is a massive, huge, large spectacular different question, concept, idea and question here. A file is a think you "open", and if you running windows software, then to open a file on some other "thing", then you need to be running the windows file system on that "thing". However, that tends to mean you have to run Samba or some other system that allows use of the file system. However, if you running a database instance like MySQL? Then you don't use a file on that "thing" or "open" some file, but are able to connect to the database (and the database system will do all the reading of data behind the scenes).

so, if you are running an instance of MySQL on that "thing", then without question that is the best choice (as opposed to some file based database - don't try that - it will not work well, and in most cases cannot work).

So, if you have MySQL running on that "thing"?
Then on your windows box, fire up say MySQL workbench or whatever your favorate database mangemenet tool is, and see if you can connect? You have to use IP address, since that device will VERY un-likly to appear as a computer on a windows network. (you need a compatible windows network stack on that device for this to work). But hitting the device by IP address with MySQL workbench, or your other mentioned database manager tool/software should work fine.

Once your database managemtn software works and connects to that device? When THEN and ONLY then can you try connecting to that "thing" from Visual Studio and your applicaiton/software you are planning to create + write. In this case, then the machine running that software will require a set of ODBC MySQL drivers to have been installed. you can of course also consider inttsalling the MySQL providers for .net if you want to use a MySQL provider as opposed to using the ODBC provider in Visual Studio.

You tend to have 3 choices:
oleDB provider.  - this is going out of flavor quite fast. But it is often used say for connecting to MS-Access databases in .net. However, this requires a valid direct windows path to the Access file. so, unless this is standlone desktop software, then I would not use Access, and in fact I would not use the .net oleDB provider either.

Next choice:
ODBC provider in .net. This is not so popular either, but it is a REALLY nice choice. The reason is that by using/choosing the ODBC provider, then you can change a connection from say SQL server to MySQL or even an MSAccess database, and FAR LESS changes to existing code is then required. So, don't ignore the great choice of using the ODBC provider in .net

Next choice:
sqlproivder. This is the most common, but that assumes you are using SQL server with your .net application. You see this referred sometimes as "ado.net", but "sqlProvider" is a better name. (the base objects such as datarow, datatable, dataset is the supposed "ado.net", and these objects are the SAME regardless of what .net provider technology you choose.

Next choice:
In place of ODBC, or the sqlProvider? I believe that MySQL does have a .net MySQLProvider.

Now in all of the above 3-4 choices? Only the top most connection objects such as:
sqlCommand (or oledbSqlCommand, or ODBCSqlCommand), and connection objects change. All code that follows really will be the SAME for all providers you choose + use. But, if you choose ODBC drivers, then you can change the connection string, and not even have to change your top most data connection technology (your providers).

In Summary:
If you have a choice of running MySQL, or some other database server that allows a socket based connection in place of a file system? Without a doubt, choose that road.

SQLite, or say MS-Access are both file based. And when it comes to "devices" and smaller computers, then you close 99% of your connection options. a file based system does not allow you to connect by IP address, and MySQL or any server based database does allow these connection options. The result is far greater ease to connect to a running service/instance of that database system as opposed to a file based database system.

If you were to JUST run software stand alone on the Raspberry? Then sure, go with SQLite, as it is file based. But, if you needing external use of that data, and you not using/supporting say web service calls on that device? Then hands down go with a NON file based database - one that allows external socket connections via IP address (something that file based system don't allow).